# Why does importing something ruin my entire code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple chrome extension that grabs a user's selected text using Chrome Tabs API. I'd like to import a Hugging Face API eventually, but when I import the required model, my Chrome Tabs API no longer executes. The selected text no longer appears inside the p tag I created in HTML. I tried wrapping the import line in  tabs and it still does not work. I am wondering if anyone can help to see why importing this is causing the rest of my code to not execute properly?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
  document.getElementById("new-task").innerHTML  =  (selection[0])
});

import { pipeline } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xenova/transformers@2.4.1';
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <p type="text" id="new-task" class="new-task" contenteditable="true"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "X",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["myscript.js"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Manifest V3 is very strict about loading external script (this is to avoid arbitrary malicious script from being executed). You will need to configure the content security policy accordingly but even then I don't know if it will pass the review. In addition content scripts no longer support module imports, you can only do it in background scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is if there are any errors or issues with the imported module from Hugging Face. If there is a problem with that module, it might break the rest of your code.

```
try {
  import { pipeline } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xenova/transformers@2.4.1';
  // Any code that depends on the imported module
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error importing Hugging Face Transformers:', error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was a super easy fix. All I had to do was add this line in my json file.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xenova/transformers@2.4.1; object-src 'self'"
```